# How to combine images of different color modes using EBImage?

Tags: r, image, ebimage

I have around 400 images which I want to combine using `abind` function of `EBImage` R package. But it returns me the following error

> Error in abind(..., along = along) : images have different color modes

An example data to reproduce the error

```
library(EBImage)
img1 <- readImage(system.file("images", "sample-color.png", package="EBImage"))
dim(img1)

img2 <- channel(img1, 'grey')

z = abind(img1, img2, along=2)
```

How to convert all the images to single band grayscale image so that `abind` can be run without any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images all need to have the same color mode. If you convert your grayscale images to RGB, then you can use `abind` and won't lose any information in the process.

```r
library(EBImage)

img1 <- readImage(system.file("images", "sample-color.png", package="EBImage"))
dim(img1)
#> [1] 768 512   3

img2 <- channel(img1, 'grey')

plot(img2)
```

[image]

```r
z = abind(img1, toRGB(img2), along=2)

plot(z)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Actually, I am having >400 images and I don't know which images are having a single band and which are having RGB bands. To recreate the error I have given a simple example. First I am making a list of files and then reading the image files using `list_of_images <- lapply(files, readImage)`

Comment: @UseR_10085 Just convert them all to rgb. `list_of_images <- lapply(list_of_images, toRGB)`